# Regular expression matching sentence

Tags: regex

I need regular expression which would match a sentence in a text file. By sentence I mean a string which starts with capital letter and ends with a period. So far I've came up with this:

```regex
[A-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9_,"#;.() \t]+[.]$
```

It's kind of working, but there's a little problem. When there are few sentences in one line, it sums them up and count as one. Any tips how to fix it?

Comment: Replace `+` with `+?`. Read about [greedy and non-greedy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: That and getting rid of $ helped, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regular expression

```
[A-Z]{1}[^.]*.
```

Comment: A single '.' matches any character, you need to quote it.

Comment: In this case though i don't think he does as it will only ever be a full stop, as before it is a pattern that matches anything that isnt a fullstop.

Comment: Fixed version: `[A-Z][^\.]*\.`

Answer (score 0):

I would extend this to `[A-Z][\s\S]+?[.?!]+`. "LOOK OUT!!" is a sentence in my book. Also allows for sentences with whitespace between them.